# How to set postgres password when creating odoo container?

Tags: docker, odoo

I need some command to create odoo and postgres containers but using `-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=...`  like this:

```
docker run -p 5000:5432   -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=... --name db postgres:9.6

docker run -tid -p 9000:8069 -v $path/addons:/mnt/extra-addons  --name od --link db:db -t odoo:12
```

Answer (score 0):

odoo image accepts a `PASSWORD` env

> PASSWORD: The password of the postgres role with which Odoo will
>   connect. If you used a postgres container, set to the same value as
>   POSTGRES_PASSWORD. Defaults to odoo.

```
docker run -p 5000:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgres-passwd --name db postgres:9.6
# or
docker run -p 5000:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=weak_pwd --name db postgres:9.6

docker run -tid -p 9000:8069 -e PASSWORD=weak_pwd -v $path/addons:/mnt/extra-addons --name od --link db:db -t odoo:12
```

Comment: thank you @Siyu, and how to create /run/secrets/postgres-passwd

Comment: i dont use docker compose

Comment: `/run/secrets/postgres-passwd` is only an example path if you really want to pass in password with file (volume or docker secret). If you don't need to use a file, just use `docker run -p 5000:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=weak_pwd --name db postgres:9.6`

Comment: can you explain me please: /run/secrets/postgres-passwd is only an example path if you really want to pass in password with file (volume or docker secret)      I have this error when i try this command: [$ echo "odooo" | docker secret create pg_password -
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again 
]

Comment: You just need to create a file with your password in it, and then pass it into the container using volume.

Comment: i have created file but how to pass it into the container db using volume.

Comment: `docker run -p 5000:5432 -v your_pwd_file_path:/psql-pwd -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/psql-pwd --name db postgres:9.6`, check how to use docker volume.

Comment: i have runing last command and:  
`docker run -tid -p 9000:8069 -e  -v $path/addons:/mnt/extra-addons --name od --link db:db -t odoo:12 ` 
 but i have still this error in logs of odoo container: 
`File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "odoo" `

Comment: but when i execute commad `$ docker exec -it db bash -c "cat psql-pwd"` it print 
`mypassword`, also the file.txt in `-v path/file.txt:psql-pwd` containt string `mypassword`

Comment: Yes you've successfully **set** a password on the db but you did not provide it to your odoo container who is trying to connect to the db.

Comment: because it will be secret, if i passed it like `docker run -tid -p 9000:8069 -e PASSWORD=mypassword -v $path/addons:/mnt/extra-addons --name od --link db:db -t odoo:12`  some people can see the password!